# How to resolve "Cannot read property 'router' of undefined" in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

I am facing this issue

> Cannot read property 'router' of undefined This error is located at:
> in NavigatorReduxWrapper (created by Connect(NavigatorReduxWrapper))
> in Connect(NavigatorReduxWrapper) (at App.js:24) in Provider

Here is the expo snack:
[Expo Snack here](https://snack.expo.io/ByqmL4NH7)

Here is a snapshot of the issue:
[image: Snapshot of the Issue]

Answer (score 0):

This most probably is not a problem with react native. It's a simple JavaScript issue ( which could have been caused by React Native )

> cannot read property of undefined
>   Basically states that your are trying to read a key in an object, but it is undefined.

For eg:

```
const obj = {}
```

`const c = obj.a.b`

Since `obj` doesn't hold any property named `a` obj.a will throw an error cannot read property `b` of undefined.

You are having a similar issue I suppose. Find out what is undefined and rectify it.

Comment: The issue was resolved but don't know the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was resolved by directly using the nav Reducer in the combine reducer instead first combine the nav reducer to a new reducer and then combining it with appReducer. Don't know why?